# Rails 4 with offline access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to add the offline access with my rails 4 application with the reference of railscast (http://railscasts.com/episodes/248-offline-apps-part-2), but the problem with rails 4 is its not caching the JS & CSS files. its seems like

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# b84e022ceae173fbc8d0c0dff68b25e9109869d744f42f1cacebfa87b96865a7
404.html
422.html
500.html

NETWORK:
*
```

is there any way to do this with rails 4

Comment: A rule of thumb: if you refer to something, a link to it will be really helpful. Specifically, a link to that railscast.

Comment: I have updated the railscast link here http://railscasts.com/episodes/248-offline-apps-part-2

Comment: Go the solution and solved that was the JS issue

Comment: @amtest, I am having the same problem here too, check please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26248279/rackoffline-in-rails-4-1-issue. Help please