# rack::offline in rails 4.1 Issue

Tags: offline-caching, railscasts, ruby-on-rails-4.1, offlineapps, ruby-2.1

can someone give me a quick solution please? I have done this:
My routes:

```
  offline = Rack::Offline.configure  do
    cache ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("application.css")
    cache ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("application.js")
    cache ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("jquery.min.css")
    cache ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("jquery.tmpl.min.css")
    cache ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("style.js")
    # cache ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("custom.css")

    network "/"
  end
  get "/application.manifest" => offline
```

in application.html.erb:

```
<html manifest="/application.manifest">
```

in my gemfile:

```
# gem 'rack-offline'
# gem 'rack-offline', :github => 'pascalw/rack-offline'
gem 'rack-offline', :git => 'https://github.com/wycats/rack-offline.git'
```

my `Rails version: 4.1.6`, `Ruby version: 2.1.3`

this is the output at `http://localhost:3000/application.manifest` is:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# a5a8232b037b9e6234e3db79ab4b2bff8fffecd76c4124f456273146f70631b0
/assets/application.css
/assets/application.js

NETWORK:
/
```

I have also added **`ENV["RAILS_ASSET_ID"] = ""`** in application.rb as [rails cast #247 Offline Apps Part 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/247-offline-apps-part-1?view=asciicast).
Please someone advise what I am doing wrong??

Comment: i think, you need to add this to routes.rb
cache ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("jquery.js")

Comment: @amtest, I have done it the same way as you. BUT still it is not working. CACHE MANIFEST
# 0751bc091a13f29326097384145d236d9a36b7cd41c91cd9358e5f539b452b13
/assets/jquery.js
/assets/application.css
/assets/application.js
/assets/jquery.min.js
/assets/jquery.tmpl.min.js
/assets/style.css
/assets/custom.css

NETWORK:
/

Comment: in which js, you put the code for offline process?

Comment: also i didn't find these files in you routes.rb
cache ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("jquery.offline.js")
   cache ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("jquery.tmpl.min.js")
   cache ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("json.js")

Comment: It failed to work, could you share your routes file? Which rails and ruby versions were you using?

Answer (score 1):

routes.rb

```
offline = Rack::Offline.configure  do 
#cache "images/masthead.png"

cache ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("jquery.js")
cache ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("jquery_ujs.js")
cache ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("application.css")
cache ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("application.js")
cacheActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("jquery.offline.js")
cache ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("jquery.tmpl.min.js")
cache ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("json.js")
cache ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("offline_mode.js")



network "/"
end
get "/application.manifest" => offline
```

applicaiton.js something like this

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.tmpl.min
//= require jquery.offline
//= require json
//= require offline_mode
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: I believe this should be very simple, but it's weird it is giving a hard time solving it. Just caching the JS and CSS is the only problem.I have done it exactly the same way as you. but i'm not sure is if I should add the if Rails.env.production? check in my routes. when the server is running, the application.manifest page              CACHE MANIFEST
# ..
/assets/application.js
/assets/jquery.js
/assets/jquery_ujs.js
/assets/jquery.tmpl.min.js
/assets/jquery.offline.js
/assets/json.js
/assets/custom.js
/assets/validate.js
/assets/application.css
/assets/style.css
/assets/custom.css

NETWORK:
/

Comment: And did I mention I was following ryan bates rails cast #247 Offline Apps Part 1 tutorial. This sucks man, especially if I don't wanna give up.

Comment: run in firefox with firebug, and check it with firebug console, this is the way i have solved

Comment: sure. as I try it you check this question i have posted a detailed explanation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26277434/rails-4-1-6-using-rack-offline-gem-to-make-offline-app-manifest-caching-and-lo

Comment: can you paste here the development.rb also the application.html.erb

Comment: done. I have updated my questions.Also here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26277434/rails-4-1-6-using-rack-offline-gem-to-make-offline-app-manifest-caching-and-lo

Comment: Use this question, it is more detailed. I have updated it and included the files. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26277434/rails-4-1-6-using-rack-offline-gem-to-make-offline-app-manifest-caching-and-lo.